# Javascript localStorage and domains

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Because iPad/iPhone doesn't support cookies from third party sites, I want to store values in localStorage. An example on domainA might be:

```
<script src="http://domainB/something.js"></script>
```

this script on domainB can access window.localStorage and it works great. However the values are stored in domainA because that's the document's location.

If I put my script inside an iframe whose source is on domainB, then it works, but I'm trying to avoid frames. So my question is: Is there a way to get/set values in localStorage on a remote domain such that they'll be there when I visit domainB at a later time?

Comment: Dude, read your own question: **local** storage on a **remote** domain :) Just joking, I know what you mean. Don't know the answer though. But I'm with Jan on this one(+1)

Comment: Well they don't call them remoteCookies, but they exist in the domain that set them, even when set through a url referred from the prior domain. Was hoping to accomplish something similar. Simply changing it from script to iframe containing a script solves it, but was hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: Here is article about Cross-Domain localStorage http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/07/learning-from-xauth-cross-domain-localstorage/ using iFrames

Answer (score 5):

This isn't possible without your iframe workaround.

The ability to access the same localStorage object from multiple domains would violate the Same origin policy,and the spec:

> User agents must raise a SECURITY_ERR
>   exception whenever any of the members
>   of a Storage object originally
>   returned by the localStorage attribute
>   are accessed by scripts whose
>   effective script origin is not the
>   same as the origin of the Document of
>   the Window object on which the
>   localStorage attribute was accessed.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#security-localStorage

If this wasn't for iPhone, I would suggest a flash solution. But with localStorage, I think you are out of luck until they implement a cross-domain policy.